# Google thinks my portfolio project is a phishing scam

Tags: google-chrome, frontend, phishing

Basically I made a Netflix clone as a portfolio project, there is a banner along the bottom that shows it's a project built by me but when visiting the page via google chrome I get a red screen with a warning saying this:
[image: Google phishing scam warning]

Once on the page it says I may be using deceptive ads.

Any ideas how I can remedy this? Don't think employers will appreciate it lol.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is nicely done by installing an SSL certificate on it. Try it!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this with the processes below:

1. Firstly setup Google search console with these steps:

Sign in to your Google Account.
Open up Google Search Console at https://search.google.com/search-console/.
Add your website as a property to GSC by choosing one of the different ways allowed.
Verify your account using HTML file, HTML tag, Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager.
(I used the addition of HTML tag on my index.html head.)

You can find the complete process on this using this link
https://kinsta.com/blog/google-search-console/

2. Now you are logged into Google Search Console, If Google has found security problems, there’ll be a link to your Security Issues Report on the overview page where you will see a red message that your site has been blocked due to suspected copying.
3. Now, On your Security Issues Report, click the Request Review button.

This will take you to a form that asks you to describe what you did to fix the problem. Write a sentence for each of the security issues detected.

As for me, it was "Deceptive Page" under the social engineering security issue and this was my message,

"I have added the metatag line of code to my html document. Please be aware that I am only recreating popular pages as projects to show to my prospects on my mastery of HTML and CSS skills. This is strictly for educational purposes."

After a few days you will receive a response email from Google that the site has been approved, this is the solution that worked for me successfully!